# Export to PDF Power BI Dashboard for all slicer options

Tags: python, r, powerbi, dax, dashboard

I have a single page dashboard with 2 different slicers, one for country and the other for year I would like to export to PDF for all possible combinations of the slicer selection. Is that programmatically possible? Using R or Python or any other method. Need guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible in the Power BI Service, or currently supported by the Power BI REST API, it would have to be manual process to do this.